# Max/min for functions of two variables and more

Tags: analysis

For the function $f(x,y)=x^2(e^{-x^2-3x-4y^2})$ find:

(1.)The points in $\mathbb{R}^2$,where $f(x,y)$ has local extrema.

(2.)The biggest and the smallest values of $f(x,y)$ in the set $\{D:x^2+4y^2\leq5\}$

(3.)The biggest and the smallest values of $f(x,y)$  in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

(1.)As far as i know we should find the first partial derivatives for $x$ and $y$.
Than make equations when they are equal to $0$ in order to find the stationary points.Than using second partial derivatives of $x,y,xy$ in a formula to decide if the stationary point are min,max or saddle point.

(2.)As far as i know the biggest and the smallest values are amongst the stationary points inside the set $D$ in the given case and on the boundary($x^2+4y^2=5$ in this case).

(3.)Aren't the biggest and the smallest values of $f(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ amongst the stationary points from (1.) and don't they match with the biggest and the smallest values in the set $D$ in the given case?

So where i am wrong,or what else should i know to solve the all 3 parts of this problem( and similar others)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea for (1) and (2) are correct. You just need to continue with them.

For (3), notice that the function goes to zero when $x$ or $y$ goes to infinity. Also it is smooth and greater than or equal to zero everywhere. So the minimum value is zero and maximum should happen at some stationary point.